# enviar alerta por if en javascript

Tags: javascript, html

estoy creando un formulario, y tengo una situación de un campo que tiene que ser llenado dependiendo de la multipricacion de unos  si es mayor que tiene que llenar el campo si es menor q no lo tiene que llenar.

esto lo estoy realizando con javascript pero soy nuevo y no se si esta correcto el codigo por que IF

este es mi codigo: javascript

Código Javascript:

```js
        <script>
            function continuar(){
                var Num = document.getElementById("multiprica").value;
                var Acc = document.getElementById("Plan_Accion").value;
               if(Num > 4){ 
                if (Acc.length==""){
                    var errorNombre=document.createElement('p');
                    errorNombre.innerHTML= 'No escribiste tu nombre';                   
                    document.getElementById("Comentarios").appendChild(errorNombre);
                    return false;
                }
            }
            }
         </script>
```

este es mi campo que se tiene que llenar

Código HTML:

```html
<div class="col-xs-17">
                            <label for="sel1">Plan de Acción: es un plan que prioriza las iniciativas más importantes para cumplir con ciertos objetivos y metas</label>
                            <input hidden="¿QUE?" name="ID_QUE" value="1">  
                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="Plan_Accion" value="Plan_Accion"></textarea>
                        </div>
```

este es el boton que llama a la funcion javascript
Código HTML:

```html
<div class="btn-group btn-group-lg">
                              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return continuar();">Continuar</button> </div>
```

Comment: Estimado @antonio sanchez, no logro comprender cuál es la regla de negocio que estás intentando implementar, no es claro el primer texto.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tu codigo funciona con algunos cambios.  Primero, quizas tengas un error en el id de la variable `Num`.  Yo cambie el id a `multiplica`.  Luego quieres acceder al elemento con id `Plan_Accion` que en tu codigo no existe.  Yo cambie la propiedad `name` por `id` de tu text area y funciono.

```html
<script>
            function continuar(){
                var Num = document.getElementById("multiplica").innerHTML;
                var Acc = document.getElementById("Plan_Accion").value;
               if(Num > 4){ 
                if (Acc.length==""){
                    var errorNombre=document.createElement('p');
                    errorNombre.innerHTML= 'No escribiste tu nombre';                   
                    document.getElementById("Comentarios").appendChild(errorNombre);
                    return false;
                }
            }
            }
         </script> 
 
<div class="col-xs-17">
    <label for="sel1">Plan de Acción: es un plan que prioriza las iniciativas más importantes para cumplir con ciertos objetivos y metas</label>
                            <input hidden="¿QUE?" name="ID_QUE" value="1">  
                            <label id="multiplica">5</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="Plan_Accion" value="Plan_Accion"></textarea>
                        </div>


<div class="btn-group btn-group-lg">
                              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return continuar();">Continuar</button> </div>
<div id="Comentarios"></div>
```

Comment: ok, si me funciona solo que la parte de <input id="multiplica" type="text"> yo la tengo diferente, yo la tengo de esta forma <label id="multiprica"></label>, su pongo que no tiene variación pero no funciona el   if(Num > 4)

Comment: Ya edite mi respuesta.  En lugar de value tienes que usar innerHTML y ademas asegurate que el id sea el mismo.